# openerp7.0: task without any project

Tags: task, odoo

How Can i add a task without mention any project and want to set reminder for that in openerp 7.0 ?

I tried it but not getting enough response.

Please help me to dig out this problem.

Let me know if there is anything else i may help you with.

Thanks

Comment: without project you want to add task? is worthless. yourself create project name so you know this task is for this project

Comment: Hello, Please accept any answer or write something about more about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think its working in 7.0. I just created a task without describing project.
[image]

[image: Kanban View]

Answer (score 1):

without project you want to add task is worthless.
But you can create task without describing project see if you are providing service than you don't need to create project every time for every customer so you can create task directly through task menu as @Ronak Shows

and you can manage it as well as